# Various CSS files for various Media queries

Tags: html, css

I'd want to utilize multiple CSS files for different screen sizes, and I've read some articles about it, but it doesn't work when I attempt it. I only have one CSS on the page, and it's getting a little messy, so I really need some help figuring out how to utilize several CSS in my HTML. Nothing seems to function when I try to upload numerous CSS files from external files.

**Here's the HTML head, where I'm attempting to include several external CSS files.**

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style450.css" media='screen (min-width: 10px) and (max-width: 450px)'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style700.css" media='screen (min-width: 451px) and (max-width: 700px)'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style991.css" media='screen (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 991px)'>
    <script defer src="./script.js"></script>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
    <title>Developer Portfolio</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss an `and` between `screen` and `size`

Check [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) for more details

> You can also provide a media type or query inside a media attribute;
> this resource will then only be loaded if the media condition is true.
> For example:

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />

<link href="print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">

 <link
href="mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width:
600px)">
```

Notice the and after `screen`

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style450.css" media='screen and (min-width: 10px) and (max-width: 450px)'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style700.css" media='screen and (min-width: 451px) and (max-width: 700px)'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style991.css" media='screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 991px)'>
    <script defer src="./script.js"></script>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
    <title>Developer Portfolio</title>
</head>
```

Edit to use another way:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 451px) and (max-width: 700px)
{
@import url('./style700.css');
}
@media screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 991px)
{
@import url('./style700.css');
}
@media screen and (min-width: 10px) and (max-width: 450px)
{
@import url('./style991.css');
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

    <script defer src="./script.js"></script>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
    <title>Developer Portfolio</title>
</head>
```

Comment: No, it does not work.

Comment: @Mukul Can you be more specific, in your question and your comments. "Does not work" does not help.

Comment: @Mukul, how doesn't work? Are you sure you put the right `href`? This is the code I commonly use and works for me

Comment: Please have a look at the link I'm sharing to see what I'm doing wrong.https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1G3ZbMNp8bp1KDc_HdgCtdj2Jec7UB4ON?usp=sharing

Comment: @Mukul, I tested your code. Seems work for me (the style sheet part). I tested it by using chrome developer tool to test in different screen size. Are you sure you have the right `href` ? Note that the and is necessary (if you doesn't have it, doesn't make sense (tested))

Comment: No, it's not functioning; I create a hamburger menu for mobile screens. Also, you can see how the nav should appear in responsiveness in the design folder.

Comment: @Mukul, interesting, if it doesn't appear it might be the problem of your style. I just create a very simple example and by giving different color (stylesheet) to body based on screen size and that works also, I have to notice you that the default `.style` will always  there

Comment: The website is responsive when I use a single CSS file with a media query. See https://jsfiddle.net/Mukulgt/s13rwebm/ for further information. When I use a single CSS file, it works, but when I use multiple CSS files, it doesn't.

Comment: @Mukul,I can't see anything use jsfiddle, but I edit and update the code to use another way. Check if works for you!

Comment: @Mukul, I do some research today regard to this problem, you should add <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" /> to your code ( I put it in first code snippet), I tested with three style sheet and seems to work

Comment: I've included that line, which you can see in the snippet I provided at the beginning of this article.